# User pick a contact from address book using new iOS 9's Contacts framework

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios9

With iOS 9 the old Address Book API will be deprecated and we will have to use the new **Contacts** framework for any contacts-related feature.

My question, is there any way to present a View Controller so the user can pick a contact the same way you did with the Address Book framework?

If not, I suggest a discussion about which is the best solution for that, as we will have to stick to this framework from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the solution you are looking for is `CNContactPickerViewController`. You can find the reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ContactsUI/Reference/CNContactPickerViewController_Class/index.html). I also suggest watching the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=223) about the new Contacts Framework, as there isn't too much information yet on Stack Overflow.

Sorry,  but I do not know how to use `NSPredicate` in conjunction with this controller, and it is required.

Comment: That was definitely the class I needed.  I managed to work with it without using `NSPredicate` but if wanna do the most of the class you need to use it.  Now I'm having compatibility problems, you can check out my [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342784/cant-run-app-on-device-ios-9-frameworks-wont-codesign).