# Can't run app on device: iOS 9 frameworks won't codesign

Tags: ios, code-signing, ios9, xcode7, ios-frameworks

I'm updating an app with deployment target iOS 7 so it can work with iOS 9.  Also, I'm adding some cool iOS 8 and 9 features.  I've read a lot of article about backwards version compatibility and now that Swift 2.0 makes it easier. The things I've taken care of so far are:

- Having the Base SDK set at iOS 9 and the deployment target set at version 7
- Checking the version at runtime with `if #available(iOS 9.0, *)` when using the new APIs
- Linking the only-iOS9 frameworks optionally, as seen here:[image: Frameworks]

As you can see the two new frameworks I'm using are `ContactsUI` and `CoreSpotlight`.  When I run the app in the simulator it works perfectly, but when I try to build and run it on my device (which is running iOS 9 obviously) I get the following code signing error:

```
/path/to/a/file.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

This error appears twice, for both the ContactsUI framework and the CoreSpotlight.

At first I thought that was a compatibility issue as it appeared for the first time when I tried to run my app on a iOS 7 device (to check it ran correctly), but then the same happened with my regular and up-to-date device.

Which is the issue here? Does the code signing error have to do with the compatibility of the frameworks? And, finally, when this is solved, will my app run on all the versions I want to support?

Thanks in advance, if you need more details just comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by just removing the frameworks from the *Embedded Binaries* list.  Now I have all my frameworks only in the *Linked Frameworks And Libraries* list:

[image]

Comment: This only works until you actually run the app and it attempts to dynamically link with those frameworks.  It gets quite angry when it discovers that they aren't there.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to follow these steps

Exit your xcode,
Clear the derived data folder,
Open xcode,
Do a clean of your project folder,
re-execute the build on device